# mysql - returns false on valid INSERT syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to figure out an error thrown by mysql here, but I do not know on how to solve this issue. I had the same problem before but it was only caused by invalid syntax in values variable, but this time round I cannot find what's wrong with it. Can anyone help me out please?

My mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `merit` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` text,
  `id_num` text,
  `category` text,
  `timeoccur` text,
  `location` text,
  `remarks` text
)

ALTER TABLE `merit`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `merit`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

The php code:

```
function add_merit($d) {
    //id_user,id_num,type,time_occur,venue,description
    global $con; //this global tested and works
    foreach ($d as $k=>$v) {
        if ($v == "") {
            header('location: merit.php?method=error');
            die();
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    $ic = $d['ic'];
    $type = $d['type']; 
    $loc = $d['loc'];
    $rem = $d['rem'];
    $uid = uid(); // function call on other php, tested and works
    $rs = $con->query("INSERT INTO merit(id_user,id_num,category,timeoccur,location,remarks) VALUES ('$uid','$ic','$type','$loc','$rem')");
    die(var_dump($rs)); //this returns false
    if ($rs) {
        //header('location: merit.php?method=success');
        die('ok');
    }
    else {
        //header('location: merit.php?method=error');
        die('err');
    }
}
```

Comment: `trigger_error('query failed', E_USER_ERROR)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **selecting 6 fields** for insertion and **passing 5 values**

```
columns :- id_user,id_num,category,timeoccur,location,remarks
values :- '$uid','$ic','$type','$loc','$rem'
```

so have a look and send proper values in query.

Comment: Thank you, now I realized that timeoccur is missing it's value. I am simply did not notice this.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't passed **field** variable:-

```
$rs = $con->query("INSERT INTO merit(id_user,id_num,category,timeoccur,location,remarks) VALUES ('$uid','$ic','$type','$loc','$rem')");
```

Answer (score 2):

you have 6 fields in value.one field is missing

```
$rs = $con->query("INSERT INTO merit(id_num,category,timeoccur,location,remarks) VALUES ('$uid','$ic','$type','$loc','$rem')");
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting this wrong is because you tell mysql to edit 6 table fields but you are only giving it 5 VALUES(). They both have to equal the same amount.

Answer (score 0):

In the query you have to pass 6 field,and you are passing 5 **fields**
so update your query as follows:

```
 $rs = $con->query("INSERT INTO merit(id_num,category,timeoccur,location,remarks) VALUES ('$uid','$ic','$type','$loc','$rem')");
```